Ubuntu 24.04 Language pack not working for Italian
I installed Ubuntu 2024.04 on a new Asus Zenbook with Windows11.
The first Ubuntu installation attempt was interrupted by an error and the Something went wrong panel appeared with the advice to send the log and retry the installation.
The second attempt was successful, but I immediately noticed that the language in use is not Italian, as set in Region & Language, but English.
I read the article https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/UbuntuItaliano and I noticed that the language support was not completely installed. So I performed the actions in the Choose the language section, without success.
Then I tried to manually install the packages.
From Synaptic I verified that the following were already installed:

language-pack-it
language-pack-it-base
language-pack-gnome-it
language-pack-gnome-it-base
while it was not installed:
menu-l10n
Then I added menu-l10n to the system.
Then I restarted Ubuntu to apply the changes but I did not detect any improvement in the problem!
What can I do?

